# The filemtime () isn't working for my script, but is working fine for the script where I copied the example code

Tags: php, ajax, long-polling, filemtime

I have a **.txt** file located under some folder of my data files. Now I have created a long polling system (*actually copied the code* ) which is run by ajax.
Now the problem is that my php script is unable to fetch file modification time of the text file (it totally disregards the file).

Below I have both the original code of the author and my twerked code. The one of the author worked fine, but not mine.
Plz help.

> **The apache server is hosted on windows server**
>
> ***THe file path is absolutly correct and file exist.***

Here's the section of my code which has error

```
    while (true) {
    //**The error occurs here**
    $fileModifyTime = filectime($file);

    if ($fileModifyTime === false) {
        throw new Exception('Could not read last modification time');
    }

    // if the last modification time of the file is greater than the last update sent to the browser...
    if ($fileModifyTime > $lastUpdate) {
        setcookie('lastUpdate', $fileModifyTime);

  require 'msgread.php';
  // get file contents from last lines...
  $fileRead = tailCustom($file, 8);

        exit(json_encode([
            'status' => true,
            'time' => $fileModifyTime,
            'content' => $fileRead
        ]));

    }

    // to clear cache
    clearstatcache();

    // to sleep
    sleep(1);

}
```

here's the original code from where i copied
[the author's original polling code](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=96028195469298833052)

and here's my full code, just in case needed
[My script which has error](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=01006629661738723265)

Comment: You cannot directly link to PHP files unless you disable the interpreter for that directory.
Please also add information about your OS (and the OS of the server).

Comment:  sorry for that mistake of mine, i just hosted it on mirror site .

Comment: @AmanKumar I'm on a mobile device so I can't help you unless you put the file on the page; my iPear refuses to open the file.

Comment: Oh! I am also on mobile device.

Comment: Okay, just wait a second , I am trying

Comment: It would help us loads if you could make the programs a little smaller; is it possible to cut some of the code out without the error going away?

Comment: Maybe - `$flag = $_PSOT['flag'];` should be `$flag = $_POST['flag'];`?

Comment: okay sorry for that, i just edited the question.

Comment: also the $flag = $_PSOT['flag']; didnt work @NigelRen

Comment: With $_PSOT - $flag wouldn't have been set at all, but always worth adding - `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the top of your code to help display errors whilst your developing

Comment: yup, i have the error_reporting(E_ALL); in my full script

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your problem is that `file.txt` does not exist. have you created it and ensured that it's in the current working directory of the script?

It's impossible to say more without seeing your actual code. If you select it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> that will indent it all.

Comment: sorry for poorly arranged question. i have edited them, plz have a look